# Using ngModel within an option select

Tags: html, angular, typescript, api, angular-ngmodel

I would like to pass in an attribute from an api call to a submit function and not sure why it isn't working. I am thinking it has something to do with an option select or reformatting the input.

Experiencing the error `Error: No value accessor for form control with name: 'employee_id'`

`form.component.html`

```
<select>
 <option 
   *ngFor="let employee of employees" 
   name="employee_id" 
   [(ngModel)]="employee_id">
   {{ employee.name }}
 </option>
</select>

<button 
  (click)="submitMeetingRequirements()" 
  class="btn btn-success">
  Suggest Meeting
</button>
```

and this is the submit function from `form.component.ts`

```
submitMeetingRequirements() {
  this._meetingService.submitMeetingRequirements(
    this.employee_id)
    .subscribe(res => this.suggestions = res["suggestions"])
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Fixed with

```
<select [(ngModel)]="employee_id" name="employee_id">
  <option 
    *ngFor="let employee of employees"
    value="{{employee.id}}">
    {{ employee.name }}
  </option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the **[`[(ngModel)]`](https://angular.io/api/forms/NgModel)** on the `select` tag and not the `option` tag. Something like this:

```
<select [(ngModel)]="employee_id">
 <option 
   *ngFor="let employee of employees" 
   name="employee_id" >
   {{ employee.name }}
 </option>
</select>

<button 
  (click)="submitMeetingRequirements()" 
  class="btn btn-success">
  Suggest Meeting
</button>
```

---

Here's a [**Working Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-r5m8ke?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) for your ref.

Comment: I tried that and I get `Error: If ngModel is used within a form tag, either the name attribute must be set or the form control must be defined as 'standalone' in ngModelOptions.`

Comment: the "name" attribute goes too on the select, you can't set same name for every option in the same select. You coul'd try using `[name]="employee.name + '_id' "`, obviously the employee names have to be different

Comment: I tried that but putting i get the error message `Cannot read property 'name' of undefined`

Comment: name of undefined means that your "employee" from the list is undefined. If you use `[name]="employee.name + '_id' "` you have to set it INSIDE the select, in the option tag; otherwise, if you use `name="employee_id"` you have to use it in the select tag